# How to use HttpContext in a Windows application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, httpcontext

I want to bind a data form html to excel. In asp.net we use this.

How to I do this in a Windows application?

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename + ".xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache); // not necessarily required
Response.Charset = "";
Response.Output.Write(htmlCodeFile);
Response.End();
```

Comment: You can't do anything remotely like this in a winforms or WPF application.

Comment: is there any other way to do this? @ Ben Robinson

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The code you posted has nothing to do with a non-http based application.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. ASP.NET is not comparable to WPF or Windows Forms.

`HttpContext` is specific for ASP.NET. There is no way to reuse that on client side code. Your code prepares and sends a HTTP response from a server to a client. That scenario is not applicable to client applications.

I would suggest to just to a [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\somefile.xls", htmlCodeFile);
```